How can I access router props passed in to Vue Router in function beforeEach
I have a Vue Router routes setup like so:
[
  {
    path: '/regions',
    name: 'regions',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "regions" */ '../views/RegionsView.vue'),
    props: {
      endpoint: '/admin/regions/index'
    },
    meta: { 
      auth: true,
      role: ['admin'],
      permission: 'region-view'
    }
  }
]

I'm trying to access props from the route in the beforeEach() function, how can I do this?
router.beforeEach((
  to: RouteLocationNormalized,
  from: RouteLocationNormalized,
  next: NavigationGuardNext
) => {
  // console.log(to.props)???
  next()
})


Check the router object or the from one.

You can use the meta key to pass data in routes.
// route definition
[
  {
    path: '/regions',
    name: 'regions',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "regions" */ '../views/RegionsView.vue'),
    // props: {
    //   endpoint: '/admin/regions/index',
    // },
    meta: {
      auth: true,
      role: ['admin'],
      permission: 'region-view',
      props: {
        endpoint: '/admin/regions/index',
      },
    },
  },
];

Then, it can be accessible in the beforeEach and other guards:
// hook
Router.beforeEach((from, to, next) => {
  console.log('from', from.meta.props?.endpoint);
  console.log('to', to.meta.props?.endpoint);
  next();
});

Based on the current router page, the props data would be in from or to or none.
Finally, in the RegionsView component:
// ../views/RegionsView.vue

<script setup>
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

const route = useRoute();
console.log('props', route.meta.props?.endpoint);

</script>

